# Extract List<List<double> to list<double>

Tags: c#, .net

am trying to deserialise a json as below

```
[{"HereList":{"values":[[13.38,52.51],[13.428,52.523]]},"type":"double"}]
```

as following

```
public class HereList
{
    public List<List<double>> values { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

can someone guide how to extract the values ([[a,b],[c,d]]) into single List here.

tried some thing like this

```
HereList ge = new HereList();
        var x = ge.values;

        foreach(var val in x)//[13.38,52.51]
        {
           //Pupulate List<double> with //[13.38,52.51]
        }
```

Comment: Typically, newtonsoft Json.

Comment: `values.SelectMany(v => v)`?

Comment: So do you already have the `List<List<double>` or what?

Comment: I have a List<List<double>> ie. [[a,b],[c,d]] , now i need a list List<double>.add(a,b). @will i have deserialized using newtinsoft now i just want to have a local list populated with "values".

Comment: But i wanted to store corresponding values like 13.38,52.51 in list[0] now an getting list[0] : 13.38 list[1]:52.51. How do i achieve list[0]:13.38,52.15 .?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IEnumerable<T>.SelectMany`.

```
HereList ge = new HereList();
var allValues = ge.values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: perfect. More info on SelectMany:http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/347/selectmany#t=201608121045348689229

Comment: But i wanted to store corresponding values like 13.38,52.51 in list[0] now an getting list[0] : 13.38 list[1]:52.51. How do i achieve list[0]:13.38,52.15 .?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updated question and code example, the following should work.

To extract the inner list (assuming you want to disregard the information you have in the rest of your model) and put all that information in one big list you can do the following:

```
// Variables from your model
HereList yourCustomModel = new HereList();
List<List<double>> values = yourCustomModel.values;

// Create a new list to store your values in
List<double> allValuesInOneSingleList = new List<double>();

// Loop through each list in values and add it to your one big list
foreach(List<double> innerList in values)
{
    allValuesInOneSingleList.AddRange(innerList);
}
```

Usage of [List.AddRange(collection As IEnumerable(Of T))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

SelectMany would help if the requirement is just to flatten an jagged array, but as i stated my requirement was Array of array.

I found the answer to be :

```
double[][] lo = HereList.values.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```